# Your Mac runs a version of OS X which is lower than your project's minimum deployment target

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have created a cocoa framework and test application to check framework functionalities.I used 10.9.2 osx version. It is working fine on 10.9.2. When i am running this on osx version 10.8.5 , getting following errors.

"Your Mac runs a version of OS X which is lower than your project's minimum deployment target.

Change your project's minimum deployment target or upgrade your version of OS X."
I changed the base sdk in build setting to 10.8 , then also am getting same message.
Please anyone tell me the solution.

Comment: You have to set the "Deployment target" to 10.8, not the "Base SDK".

Comment: Apple's messages are masterpieces of conciseness and clarity. How is it that people are unable to follow simple instructions?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what is wrong for beginners in this case. I don't think there's a reason to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Deployment target to 10.8 if you want to support OSX 10.8 and above. It can be found under project settings -> info.

Answer (score 16):

The setting to change the minimum deployment version is harder to find than the previous post suggests.

It is not located in the "Project settings" in the Xcode File menu, you need to click on your project in the left-hand nav -> General tab -> Deployment target. See pic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This answer should be marked as the solution.