# Error message on mac os x 10.10 Yosemite "Change your project’s minimum deployment target or upgrade My Mac’s version of OS X."?

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

When I searched for a mac os x opengl tutorial and tried to build it, I got the following error message. I tried to change "OS X Deployment Target" to 10.10 Yosemite (which I am running), but it has no effect. I can't find any documentation online to explain what might be going wrong, nor could I find any tutorials about XCode 7. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

"My Mac runs OS X 10.10.5, which is lower than tutorial01_first_window’s minimum deployment target. Change your project’s minimum deployment target or upgrade My Mac’s version of OS X."

[image: Xcode error image]

Here is the original tutorial I downloaded and built with CMake according to the instructions:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same thing.  I'm running 10.10.5 Yosemite and am using Xcode 7.0.1 with CMake 3.3.2 and it insisted on generating 10.11 deployment targets.

This answer is a bit dated, but it got me a long way towards a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329890/2059999

I can get it to work by manually setting the OS X Deployment Target on the target binary in my project to 10.10, but CMake will clobber my change each time it gets re-run which is annoying.

Comment: Hmm, in that link he has the target selected in the left-hand pane and has the OS Deployment target changed to 10.10 just like in my picture. Why does that work on his XCode and not on mine?

Comment: @WRiker The link is a bit dated, so he's using an older version of XCode... In 7.0.1 I had to manually go to the specific target for the application in my library to run with debugging and I found the Deployment Target option.
It's annoying because each time I re-run CMake, it will reset to an OS X 10.11 target but I can limp along with this until our computer support people give us the green light to upgrade to El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after a recent upgrade of Xcode (Version 7.0.1).  It turns out that the default deployment target for it is OS X 10.11, which is higher than the one I have.  The solutions above do work.  However, to set this "permanently" in CMake, find the advanced option "CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" and set it to the one on your system, e.g. 10.10.

[Setting CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EZtF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this message with homebrew and updating Xcode from 7.3.1 to Xcode 8.1 fixed it