# Xcode error claiming OS version is less than deployment version

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to debug a dylib that I wrote, used by an application that I didn't write.  I set the dylib's scheme to specify the client app as its "executable", but when I try to run I get an error as shown below.

[image: Xcode screen shot]

As shown, the target build settings specify a deployment target of 10.6.  It seems odd that the error message talks about the "project's minimum deployment target" when target settings override project settings, but anyway the project build settings and the project Info page all say 10.6.  The Mac is running 10.7.5.  Last time I checked, 10.7 > 10.6, so what is going on?  I'm using Xcode 4.6.3.

This is the same error message as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545679/your-mac-runs-a-version-of-os-x-which-is-lower-than-your-projects-minimum-deplo), but its answers did not help me.

Comment: The app you didn't write: what is it's minimum deployment target?

Comment: @JeremyP, I'm not sure.  It was built using Delphi on Windows, not Xcode, and its Info.plist does not specify a minimum system version.  But it does launch without using Xcode, so how would Xcode know if there was a problem with it?

Comment: First of all I didn't know you could build Mac applictions with Delphi on Windows. However, to answer the question, it might be somewhere in the mach-o headers in the exe. You can use `otool` with various options to display useful information about the exe

Comment: @JeremyP, I couldn't find anything relating to deployment version in `otool` output.  My guess is that Apple is making some undocumented assumption about the Mach-O format of the executable, and if the assumption is not satisfied, they show an inappropriate error message.

Comment: Is there a separate Info.plist file in that project somewhere? You can also set a minimum version in the Info.plist. Have you looked at the build product's Info.plist to see if that says anything? Also, does the project have any .xcconfig files that might be overriding this setting? And finally, could it be that the version is specified in an old format? In my Xcode it says "macOS 10.12" not "OS X 10.12". What other options does the popup offer?

Comment: @uliwitness, I'm not sure you understood my question.  My Xcode project builds a dylib, so it doesn't have an Info.plist.  As for the pop-up, it's Xcode 4.6.3, that might explain the difference in format.